# RUNPATH is disappearing from search path after some libs are found

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm compiling a software with CMake and GCC under Ubuntu 18.
Here's the relevant CMake line:

```
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib/")
```

setting the runpath relative to the origin.

Once the software is installed using CMake, readelf gives this information:

```bash
$ readelf -a my_exe | grep RUNPATH
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../..lib/]
```

When running `LD_DEBUG=libs ./my_exe`, this is the output (shortened for readability):

```
     10093: find library=libgmp.so.10 [0]; searching
     10093:  search path=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/haswell:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/x86_64:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/haswell/x86_64:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/haswell:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/x86_64:/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib        (RUNPATH from file ./exe/my_exe)
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/haswell/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/x86_64/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/tls/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/haswell/x86_64/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/haswell/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/x86_64/libgmp.so.10
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/libgmp.so.10
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
     10093: 
     10093: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
     10093:  search path=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib      (RUNPATH from file ./exe/my_exe)
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/libpthread.so.0
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

[...]

     10093: 
     10093: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
     10093:  search path=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib      (RUNPATH from file ./exe/my_exe)
     10093:   trying file=/home/buildbot/install/exe/../lib/libc.so.6
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     10093: 
     10093: find library=libz.so.1 [0]; searching
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1

[...]

     10093: 
     10093: find library=libcrypto.so.1.1 [0]; searching
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
     10093: 
     10093: find library=libHalf-2_3.so.24 [0]; searching
     10093:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     10093:  search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/lib/tls/haswell:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/haswell/x86_64:/lib/haswell:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/haswell:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64:/usr/lib/haswell:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib        (system search path)
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/tls/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/tls/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/tls/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/lib/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/haswell/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093:   trying file=/usr/lib/libHalf-2_3.so.24
     10093: 
./exe/my_exe: error while loading shared libraries: libHalf-2_3.so.24: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Between the first and second lib, we can see that the search path from RUNPATH is greatly reduced. I imagine there's an optimization discarding all the folders that don't exist.

But then the RUNPATH is dropped (between `libc.so.6` and `libz.so.1`) from the search. Which cause an issue down the road because `libHalf-2_3.so.24` is in the `lib` directory relative to `my_exe`.

I haven't found an explanation for this behavior, and how to solve it.

Comment: Is `libz.so.1` required **directly** by your executable, or is it required by some library, on which your executable depends?

Comment: Directly, we use zlib for creating archives in the software

Comment: That is, `libz.so.1` is listed as `(NEEDED)` in the output of `readelf --dynamic my_exe`? Please, check that.

Comment: No it is not listed, not even as needed

Comment: So, `libz.so.1` is required (NEEDED) by some other library. `RUNPATH` settings of your executable don't affect on searching dependencies of the other library.

Comment: Any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Documentation for [ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) notes `DT_RPATH` attribute, which unlike to `DT_RUNPATH` affects on the searching for inner dependencies too. But generally you should fix RPATH of the library, which directly needs `libz.so.1` (or `libHalf-2_3.so.24`, as exactly given file is not found according to your description).